# memory leak when JPEG, not when PNG

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, nsdata, memory-leaks, uiimagejpegrepresentation

My application aims at saving some user photos in a PDF file in order to send the file by email. To produce a small size pdf, I want to compress my images in jpeg. When I draw jpeg to the PDF context, the pdf file is indeed much smaller than when I use PNG, but the use of JPEG leaks.

For my debugging I added a jpeg and a png file to my project.

The following call leaks :

```
UIImage * destImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.JPG"];
[destImage drawInRect:drawingFrame];
```

whereas this one does not :

```
UIImage * destImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
[destImage drawInRect:drawingFrame];
```

Is there something I'm missing ? Is it a know issue ?

I'm thinking about a workaround that would consist in using a PNG representations of my images and set a specific compression option to the pdf I generate, but did not find this in the pdf generation sdk.

Do you have an idea about it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know it is a leak and not just some hidden image caching? (I am not saying that it is... I am just wondering how you checked it).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I use Leaks Instrument from XCode. The given responsible caller is CGImageReadCreateDataWithMappedFile.